# Is this date in Zulu (UTC) timezone?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have a date string as below.

I think this implies it is in UTC timezone.

Is that correct?

`2016-10-30T15:27:02.000Z`

Comment: Yes, that's true... The `Z` at the end means *Zulu*, could be replaced by an offset of `+00:00`.

Comment: Thanks all, I just needed a quick confirmation.

Comment: Search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. According to [joda](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#UTC), the first millisecond in UTC can be represented in this format: `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`

Answer (score 1):

You correctly guessed it, thats UTC Date and Time.

ISO 8601

Which is October 30th, 2016, at 3:27 pm (+2 seconds) in Greenwich Mean Time.

For further reference you can check

[ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

[StackExchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148660/deserializing-a-string-from-json-to-datetime-in-apex-yields-invalid-format-err)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can verify it by parsing a `java.time.ZonedDateTime` from the `String` and print the offset information of it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String utcDateTime = "2016-10-30T15:27:02.000Z";
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(utcDateTime);
    System.out.println(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter
                        .ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz '==>' xxx '=' O")));
}
```

This outputs

```
2016-10-30 15:27:02 Z ==> +00:00 = GMT
```

Note: This output pattern contains redundant information for verification, see the pattern letters in the [JavaDocs of `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)